# WPF using a view to change the parents atributes

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

My program has several views that are controlled using a Hamburger menu. Inside one of these views i have made a toggle switch to change between fullscreen and windowed. The only problem is that to do this i need to change the Mainwindow.xaml from within the view. The mainwindow is a "MetroWindow"

I have tried adapting the following:

```
 Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

This works fine but when i want to use a metro specific attribute:

```
Parent.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = true;
```

It obviously doesn't contain a reference as its not a window its a metrowindow. I changed the code to a metrowindow but that wont work as it cant convert from windows.window to mahapps.metro.controls.metrowindow.

```
 MetroWindow metroParent = MetroWindow.GetWindow(this);
```

Is there anyway i can do this or run code from the mainwindow code within my view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the result:

```
MetroWindow parent = Window.GetWindow(this) as MetroWindow;
```

Comment: I have only just got enough rep to be able to do it :)